# Use a RegularExpressionValidator to allow one of two patterns at the beginning of input

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, asp.net-2.0

I've got a `RegularExpressionValidator` (ASP.NET 2.0) that I'm using to make sure that a URL entered in a text box begins properly with `http://`.  I was using a ValidationExpression of `^http://`.  Now I'm allowing `mailto` links as well, so my expression is `^http://|^mailto:`.

It works in a [regex tester](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) (set to Client-side Javascript engine) for inputs like "http://www.google.com" and "mailto:someone@anymail.net".  But the RegularExpressionValidator on my page doesn't let any valid inputs through.

I've tried the following variations, all of which work in the tester but none of which work in the validator:

- `(^http://)|(^mailto:)`
- `^(http://)|(mailto:)`
- `^http://|^mailto:`
- `^(http://|mailto:)`
- `http://|mailto:`
- `^((http://)|(mailto:))`

The declaration of the validator is this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEditUrl" runat="server"
   ControlToValidate="txtEditUrl" ErrorMessage="Url must begin with 'http://' or 'mailto:'"
   ValidationExpression="^((http://)|(mailto:))" Display="Dynamic"
   ValidationGroup="myGroup" />
```

My intent is to allow any input that begins with either http:// or mailto:.  What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: The [MSDN page on Regular Expressions in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx) says:

> You do not need to specify beginning of string and end of string matching characters (^ and $)—they are assumed. If you add them, it won't hurt (or change) anything—it's simply unnecessary.

Does this mean that it's assuming that my input can't have anything in it that doesn't conform to my regex (i.e. that it should be either `http://` or `mailto:`)?  If so, then why did my original pattern of `^http://` work?

Comment: I don't have a windows development machine to actively try out stuff, but have you tried `^((http://)|(mailto:))`?

Comment: @Michael - I just tried that, and it didn't work.  I'm starting to wonder whether it's not related to the regex I'm using...

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to make the call to RegularExpressionValidator?

Comment: I took a look at the Regex page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx and it looks like you need to escape the semi-colon and slashes. See their URL example.

Comment: @Michael - It looks like your answer below does just that, but it fails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `:`: and `/`.

Also, I wonder if RegularExpressionValidator doesn't automatically presume that the whole string matches and implies $ at the end. 
Try:

```
^((http\:\/\/)|(mailto\:))(.+)$
```

Comment: I wonder if RegularExpressionValidator doesn't automatically presume that the whole string matches and implies `$` at the end. Maybe try `^((http\:\/\/)|(mailto\:))(.+)$`?

Comment: That did it.  So the MSDN page my question references is correct.  But the MSDN page you referenced in your comment seems to imply (under "Using ^ and $") that it's something the user has to take care of.  Weird.  And if that's true, then why did my original http:// pattern work?

Comment: The regular expression tester on the website probably uses the Regex class and not RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: That would make sense, when it's using the .NET engine; when it's using the client-side engine, I'd guess it's using JS.

But originally, when I was only allowing `http://`, the validator allowed through inputs like `http://www.google.com`.  Given the cause of the issues with the newer pattern ($ is assumed at the end), that should not have worked.  Why did it?

Comment: Not sure. You could pose this as another question to get help from a wider audience of people. Most people won't see your update to the question since the question is set to answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping every non-alphanumeric character, one at a time, including the parantheses.  I imagine its just one of those - every regex implementation has different characters that are metacharacters by default.